# How to define Indices on huge table (>38.700.000 rows) using group by, where and order by clause

Tags: mysql, performance, indexing, myisam, database-partitioning

I'm trying to speed up my Queries on a huge MySQL-Table (more than ~38.700.000 rows) but I can't figure out what to do. I read dozens of related Articles and even messed around with the MySQL-Documentation.
I confess, I need help!

This is my current Table-Structure:

```
    CREATE TABLE `bz_all_part` (
        `salon` smallint(6) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
        `datum` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '936868149',
        `datumuhrzeit` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '936868149',
        `ma` mediumint(6) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
        `ztyp` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
        `zart` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
        `storno` tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
        `betrag` int(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
        `betragorig` int(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',

       KEY `test1` (`ztyp`,`storno`,`ma`),
       KEY `test2` (`ztyp`,`storno`),
       KEY `test3` (`ma`),
       KEY `test4` (`ztyp`,`datum`),
       KEY `test5` (`datumuhrzeit`,`ztyp`,`storno`),
       KEY `test6` (`ma`,`ztyp`,`datumuhrzeit`),
       KEY `test7` (`ztyp`,`storno`,`datumuhrzeit`),
       KEY `test8` (`ztyp`,`storno`,`datumuhrzeit`,`zart`),
       KEY `test9` (`salon`,`ma`,`zart`,`ztyp`,`storno`,`datumuhrzeit`)
    ) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8

    /*!50100 PARTITION BY RANGE (datumuhrzeit)
    (PARTITION s0 VALUES LESS THAN (1391210639) ENGINE = MyISAM,
     PARTITION s1 VALUES LESS THAN (1393889039) ENGINE = MyISAM,
        ...
     PARTITION s47 VALUES LESS THAN (1514762639) ENGINE = MyISAM) */;
```

The Fields ****datum**** and ****datumuhrzeit**** are Unix-Timestamps. I thought they are faster than **datetime**.

As you can see, I have a lot of Partitions (they speed up the query, when I choose a smaller Period) and some Test-Indices. They don't help much.

I read a lot about that Columns in Multi-Column-Indices should be in the correct Order (as they are used in the query). I tried this with Index ***test7*** and ***test9***, but I haven't had luck.

This is the query I use:

```
SELECT 
    *,
    ROUND(betrag / anzBelege, 2) as umsJeBeleg,
    ROUND(betragorig / anzBelege, 2) as umsJeBelegOrig
FROM
    (SELECT 
        count(distinct concat(salon, datumuhrzeit)) as anzBelege,
        SUM(zart) as anzServices,
        SUM(ROUND(betrag / 100, 2)) as betrag,
        SUM(ROUND(betragorig / 100, 2)) as betragorig
    FROM 
        bz_all_part
    WHERE
            ztyp = 0
        AND
            storno = 0
        AND
            datumuhrzeit >= unix_timestamp("2013-01-01 00:00:00")
        AND
            datumuhrzeit <= unix_timestamp("2018-07-01 00:00:00")
    GROUP BY
        salon,
        ma, 
        zart) core
```

When I run this query, the result contains 526607 rows and it takes around 206 Seconds.

Explain outputs:

```
id|select_type|table      |type|possible_keys    |key  |key_len|ref        |rows    |Extra
--|-----------|-----------|----|-----------------|-----|-------|-----------|--------|-----
1 |PRIMARY    |<derived2> |ALL |NULL             |NULL |NULL   |NULL       |22955178|NULL
2 |DERIVED    |bz_all_part|ref |test1,2,4,5,7,8,9|test2|5      |const,const|22955178|Using where; Using filesort
```

***Possible Keys*** contains Index test7 and test9, but it uses neither of them, but test2. I have no idea why!

I would really appreciate some help regarding this topic.

Thank you very much!

Additional Info:

- The Server is not the fastest (It's just a Test-Server)
- We expect a grow of ~15.000.000 rows each year
- This above query will be one of dozens (they are all quite different and used to get Statistics)

Edit 1:
Output of:

```
SELECT * FROM bz_all_part PROCEDURE ANALYSE();


Field_name                  |Min_value| Max_value|Min_length|Max_length|Empties_or_zeros|Nulls|Avg_value_or_avg_length|Std        |Optimal_fieldtype 
----------------------------|---------|----------|----------|----------|----------------|-----|-----------------------|-----------|-----------------------------
db.bz_all_part.salon        |0        |60974     |1         |5         |1               |0    |13357.9473             |17056.3346 |SMALLINT(5) UNSIGNED NOT NULL
db.bz_all_part.datum        |0        |1490911200|1         |10        |1               |0    |1440703052.6328        |427695.2284|INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL
db.bz_all_part.datumuhrzeit |0        |1490989761|1         |10        |1               |0    |1440755042.1115        |460817.3074|INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL
db.bz_all_part.ma           |0        |60127     |1         |5         |43              |0    |1166.8595              |7840.3516  |SMALLINT(5) UNSIGNED NOT NULL
db.bz_all_part.ztyp         |0        |40181     |1         |5         |26257963        |0    |1140.0327              |4650.5316  |SMALLINT(5) UNSIGNED NOT NULL
db.bz_all_part.zart         |0        |55158     |1         |5         |1               |0    |3338.9947              |8165.2681  |SMALLINT(5) UNSIGNED NOT NULL
db.bz_all_part.storno       |0        |2         |1         |1         |38604746        |0    |0.0074                 |0.1111     |ENUM('0','1','2') NOT NULL
db.bz_all_part.betrag       |-45240   |269900    |1         |6         |2123326         |0    |1438.2915              |1916.8851  |MEDIUMINT(6) NOT NULL
db.bz_all_part.betragorig   |-45240   |1711250   |1         |7         |2546610         |0    |1491.6800              |2089.4486  |MEDIUMINT(7) NOT NULL
```

**Edit 2:**

```
CREATE TABLE `bz_all_part2` (
  `salon` smallint(6) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `datum` timestamp NOT NULL,
  `datumuhrzeit` timestamp NOT NULL,
  `ma` mediumint(6) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `ztyp` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `zart` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `storno` enum('0','1','2') DEFAULT NULL,
  `betrag` mediumint(7) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `betragorig` mediumint(7) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  KEY `test1` (`ztyp`,`storno`,`datum`,`zart`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

New Explain output:

```
id|select_type|table      |type|possible_keys    |key  |key_len|ref        |rows    |Extra
--|-----------|-----------|----|-----------------|-----|-------|-----------|--------|-----
1 |PRIMARY    |<derived2> |ALL |NULL             |NULL |NULL   |NULL       |2243987 |NULL
2 |DERIVED    |bz_all_part|ref |test1            |test1|6      |const,const|2243987 |Using index condition; Using where; Using filesort
```

Output of:

```
SELECT * FROM bz_all_part PROCEDURE ANALYSE();
```

Is nearly the same as above

I shrunk my table to **5.000.000** rows to get some faster results.

Any more Ideas?

Comment: You have too many indexes. You use MyISAM, which relies on HDD. InnoDB is able to store working data in RAM, making it faster to perform I/O operations. `TIMESTAMP` data type stores an integer internally, but it displays the value to you as `DATETIME` - you should use that instead if `int`. Adding indexes doesn't make query faster, if, like in your case, there are a lot of records that satisfy the condition (in WHERE clause or in JOIN/subquery etc).  Your date range is between year 2013 and 2018 - there's probably going to be A LOT of records satisfying that condition.

Comment: can you post us the output from **SELECT * FROM bz_all_part PROCEDURE ANALYSE();** . It can take a some time. also keys test2,test7 and test8 are the same. you only use test8. Also i am not sure if you use the best Storage Engine. MyISAM performs not good by writes

Comment: @BerndBuffen: I've edited my Question.

Comment: @Mjh: I'm about to change my Table accordingly to your suggestions. This needs some time. I'll get back to you.

Comment: There are some things you can do. These are, however, dependent on the use of the table (even when writing). It starts with STORAGE ENGINE and goes through the order of the fields in an index and also the query can be optimized. If you like you can call me gladly, then we can discuss these things and post only the results. I am available today from ca 18:00 clock

Comment: @Mjh: I changed the Storage-Engine to **InnoDB** and deleted not needed Indices. I changed the `datum` and `datumuhrzeit` columns to Timestamp, also. I truncated my rows to 5 Million to get faster results for testing. But the Query takes ~45 Seconds to load the result of 59577 rows.

Comment: @BerndBuffen: Sorry, my English isn't the best (I'm from Germany), when talking :-) I would like to text about this issue (not restricted to SO). But thank you very much!

Comment: which index takes the query now ?

Comment: There is just one Index left (test1: (`ztyp`,`storno`,`datum`,`zart`)). I have updated my Question with all changes.

Comment: @M. Fellinger - i am also from germany :-)

Comment: try this (only for test): create a new index **test10** with the fields **alon,  ma,  zart** and change the FROM line to **FROM 
        bz_all_part  FORCE INDEX (test1) FORCE INDEX FOR GROUP BY (test10)**

Comment: InnoDB requires configuring. Default setting uses only 128MB of RAM to store the working data-set. To increase it, you need to change configuration variable `innodb_buffer_pool_size` and restart MySQL for setting to take effect. This is the reason why database servers usually have lots of RAM (128GB and more). Doing this shifts I/O from HDD to memory, which is several thousand times faster.

Comment: @BerndBuffen: still ~46 Seconds but explain says now ''Using index condition; Using MRR; Using filesort'''

Comment: i will check it this evening with a test table and report you later

Comment: @BerndBuffen I think Mjh made a point. I checked the innodb_buffer_pool_size-Variable and its set to ~ 128MB. Currently I have no choice to increase the value until we ordered the new Server.

Comment: have you checked this 2 vars ? **SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'innodb_file_per_table';
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'innodb_buffer_pool_size';** ? How much memory you can use for the database ?

Comment: `innodb_file_per_table` is ON and `innodb_buffer_pool_size` is 128MB.

Comment: We just got the new Server and the info_db_buffer_pool_size is 4GB and now the query runs within 125 Seconds (on 38 Million rows). I think the increasdedbuffer-size and the new indices have helped!

Thank you all for your help!

Answer (score 0):

```
   KEY `test1` (`ztyp`,`storno`,`ma`),
   KEY `test2` (`ztyp`,`storno`),
```

The second is redundant because it is a prefix of the first, drop it.

Switch to InnoDB *and* provide a `PRIMARY KEY`.  MyISAM is going away in the next release.

Changing `storno` from `TINYINT` to `ENUM` has no impact on table size or query performance.  However, changing to `NULL` may have small negative impact.

The 48 partitions *probably* slowed the query down some, rather than speeding it up.  You already have the 'perfect' index: (`ztyp`,`storno`,`datumuhrzeit`).

"526607 rows 206 seconds" -- but how many rows did it have to scan to do the subquery?  *That* is the costly part, I think.  In fact, why don't you pull the subquery out, time it; then if it is most of the total, let's focus on it.

But, enough of that.  Probably *this* is the answer...

Build and maintain a Summary Table.

It would have, perhaps...

```
PRIMARY KEY(salon, ztyp, storno, month)
SUM(zart) AS sum_zart
SUM(...)  etc
```

Where `month` is `datumuhrzeit` truncated to the month (or day or whatever makes sense).
Think through whether such a table would let you run the subquery.

[*More on Summary Tables*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/summarytables) .

This may run the inner query 10 times as fast.